# how to add an overlay color to an image without adding it to a div

Tags: html, css

I have a slider with cards. I want to add an transparent color on the image on hover.
if i put the image in a div it will be ruined.
here is my code for one card

```
div class="card col-12 col-sm-1" >
     <img src="../assets/images/images.png" class="card-img-top" 
   alt="...">
          
                            
                                                    
                        <h4 class="card-title p-2 m-1">
                            لوله مانسمان وارداتی
                        </h4>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text">لورم ایپسوم متن ساختگی با تولید سادگی نامفهوم از صنعت چاپ و با استفاده از</p>
                            <a href="#" class="card-call-link">

                            <span class="slider-call">
                                <p>تماس با کارشناسان مربوطه</p>
```

Comment: Do you mean change it opacity on hover? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity

Comment: no i wanna add a color on image on hover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example with opacity and filter and I extended example based on comment,I hope it helps.

```css
.img1:hover{
filter: grayscale(30%) blur(1px);
}
.img2:hover{
opacity:.8;
}

div:hover{
width:fit-content;
background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.4);
}
.img3{
 position:relative;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<img class="img1" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSIIehVJqIVxagF-1qZ_elmAoH3FCfWnhHoSA&usqp=CAU"/>

<img class="img2" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSIIehVJqIVxagF-1qZ_elmAoH3FCfWnhHoSA&usqp=CAU"/>

<div>
<img class="img3" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTm3jFWGKHucgSVFKi_hv9422Ee8zGKkQOdsA&usqp=CAU"/>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you but I can't add a specific color with this.

Comment: I updated the answer, now you can filter the image by a color.

Answer (score 0):

you can use opacity

```
opacity: 21%;
```

or filter in to add some affects

```
filter: grayscale(50%) blur(7px);
```

in the img directly